# ShuffleMerge using recursion

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, tail-recursion

```
struct node* ShuffleMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b) {
struct node* result;
struct node* recur;
 if (a==NULL) return(b); // see if either list is empty
  else if (b==NULL) return(a);
  else {
  // it turns out to be convenient to do the recursive call first --
  // otherwise a->next and b->next need temporary storage.
  recur = ShuffleMerge(a->next, b->next);
  result = a; // one node from a
  a->next = b; // one from b
  return(result);
  }
}
```

Code not working, cannot access elements after B...

Comment: I suggest you try debugging using pen and paper-draw the simplest non trivial example of a and b you can, then work your way through the code, writing the new values of each of the variables as you go.  There is at least one bug in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple 'pen and paper' debugging session, using the simplest non-trivial inputs I can think of:

```
S(a=1->2, b=3->4)                1->2 2->N 3->4 4->N
recur := S(2, 4)
   recur := S(a=N, b=N)
       return N
   recur := N
   result:= 2
   a     := 2->4                 1->2 2->4 3->4 4->N
recur := N
result:= 1->2->4
a     := 1->3->4                 1->3 2->4 3->4 4->N
return 1->3->4
```

Was that what the code was supposed to do for this case?  If not, why not?

I hope this technique is useful in future.